# How to get information of cluster nodes with Powershell and print node status

Tags: powershell, windows-clustering

I want to perform validation and print output of cluster node in powershell

cmd

Get-ClusterNode

output:

| Name | ID | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| node1 | 1 | Up |
| node2 | 2 | Up |
| node3 | 3 | Up |
| node4 | 4 | Up |

for instance in this output, I need to check if the node status is up then print node name and state
and if any of node is down then it should print that one of the node is down with the name of down node.

I have no background of scripting but I wrote this script can anyone please check if this would give the proper output, I used foreach since state of all node is need to be checked and then I tried to print it.

thanks!!

```
$node = Get-Clusternode
$state = $node.state

foreach state$
{
    if ( $state -match 'Up')
    {
        'File Share Witness status =' + ' ' + "$state"
        exit0
    }

    if ( $state -match 'Failed')
    {
        'File Share Witness status =' + ' ' + "$state"
        exit0
    }
}
```

Comment: "if the node status is up then print node name and state and if any of node is down then it should print on of the node is down with the name of down node." - isn't the output from `Get-ClusterNode` already showing you exactly that? It lists each node by name and whether it's `Up` or not